# How query on some subdocument mongodb

Tags: mongodb, database

There is a colloction, that have multi subdocument per document as follow:

```
db.test.insert(
{
    "username" : " user1",
    "Items" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Total",
            "value" : 53951
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "n1",
            "value" : 5711
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "n2",
            "value" : 5477
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "n3",
            "value" : 11444
        }
    ]
})
db.test.insert(
{
    "username" : " user2",
    "Items" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Total",
            "value" : 43951
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "n1",
            "value" : 5011
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "n2",
            "value" : 5117
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "n3",
            "value" : 1444
        }
    ]
})
db.test.insert(
{
    "username" : " user3",
    "Items" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Total",
            "value" : 51421
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "n1",
            "value" : 5241
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "n2",
            "value" : 1477
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "n3",
            "value" : 9244
        }
    ]
})
```

I want to select Items that its name is "Total" as following:

```
{
    "username" : " user1",
    "Items" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Total",
            "value" : 53951
        }
    ]
}

{
    "username" : " user2",
    "Items" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Total",
            "value" : 43951
        }
    ]
}

{
    "username" : " user3",
    "Items" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Total",
            "value" : 51421
        }
    ]
}
```

I used some queries like `db.test.find({"Items.name":"Total"},{"Items.name":1,"Items.value":1})` . But its not correct. 
Do is any way, or I should change Data Structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.test.find({Items:{$elemMatch:{name:'Total'}}});
```

For more information check [MongoDB docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/).

Comment: db.test.find({},{Items:{$elemMatch:{name:'Total'}}});